# How to merge two Pandas columns that are not identical into 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to be able to combine two specific columns from a dataframe that aren't identical into a new column.

| Name | Team or Club | After School Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jill | Yes | Drama |
| Alex | Yes | Soccer |
| John | No | Tutor |
| Nick |  |  |
| Sean | Yes | Basketball |
| Lisa | No |  |
| Steph |  | Dance |

In this case I would like to combine columns 'Team or Club' and ' After School Activity' into a new column.

The new column should look like this.

| Combined |
| --- |
| Yes, Drama |
| Yes, Soccer |
| No, Tutor |
|  |
| Yes, Basketball |
| No |
| Dance |

Sorry that this isn't in the right formatting and I put a table instead of showing my code or output. I'm new to this, I'm not sure how to do that yet.

Comment: `df[['Team or Club', 'After School Activity']].agg(', '.join, axis=1).str.strip(', ')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from numpy import nan
```

Just use `apply()` method and `replace()` method:

```
df=df.replace(nan,' ',regex=True)

combined=df[['Team or Club', 'After School Activity']].apply(','.join,1)
```

Now If you print `combined` you will get your desired output